# How to configure ssh client to automatically execute commands on connect?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I frequently connect to servers through a user I share with other colleagues, every time I connect to each server I execute a couple of commands like `bash`, `set -o vi`, etc.

I would want to know if there is a way to tell the ssh client utility to execute those on the remote server before handing me the control.

Basically something like this:

```
echo "bash; set -o vi; <DONT_EXIT>;" | ssh user@host
```

Anything built in the ssh client utility? Any workarounds that are executed from MY side? I am aware of workarounds on the server side, which are not what I am looking for. I can't find this anywhere, so, I am basically confirming that it actually can't be done.

I am using Linux with the default OpenSSH ssh utility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter I was looking for is: -t which would force the ssh client to allocate a terminal , so it looks like this:

```
ssh -t user@host "bash -o vi"
```

This will get me to auto enable the vi mode upon connect, but executing more commands is trickier since if I added more commands afterwards they will be executed after exit from bash and immediately exit everything, so all commands must be executed before it.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/a/56181/120953, for setting the command in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys so that you don't have to specify it client-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the commands to the file:

```
~/.bashrc
```

when you login, first execute these commands, last it give you the shell.

Comment: That has to be done server-side, and would affect the other colleagues who share the account.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps finish off your string of commands with your shell you want to interact with?

```
ssh user@host "bash -c 'set -o vi; bash'"
```

I tested this and it seems to run the initial commands and then be interactive, however stdout isn't coming back properly.  Hopefully someone else can point out the solution to that.